# Keyboard problems 2.8

Tags: interface

Whenever i open 2.8 beta it will not let me use my keyboard. I cannot create any text or use hotkeys. I have tried a few versions but they all have this problem for me. Do you have any ideas what would cause this?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 latest update

Comment: Did you ever get your keyboard working? I'm having the same problem.
Kevin.

Answer (score 1):

**Re-download and extract the Blender zip file making sure everything is copied over.**

When you downloaded Blender 2.8 Beta it should have been in a zip file. Extracting the zip file would have taken time and if not every part of the zip file was extracted then parts of blender don't work properly

I learnt this by running Blender before everything had extracted.

Here is a photo of my Blender folder:
[image]

It has 72 items in it (including the '2.80' folder) and Blender runs fine.

My guess would be the part of the file which detects keyboard clicks is not there so re-download the .zip file and extract it making sure everything is copied.

I can't say for sure if this will work but hopefully it does. If it doesn't then I don't know what else to do and I am sorry.